# integrating oracle hospitality pms with laravel application

Tags: laravel, oracle, api

How to integrate oracle hospitality opera 5.5 pms with my laravel application to get room information? Is there any REST api for connecting with this pms?

My intention is to get room owner details by passing room number to pms. Heard about fias.But  how to connect with my application. Is there any proper api url?

Answer (score 0):

You will need use OEDS/OWS API.

OPERA Web Services (OWS) is a collection of Windows-based Web Services that provides access to OPERA functionality, and also acts as an interface between OPERA and external applications, such as a Web booking engine.

OWS is designed using the Microsoft .NET Framework and is compatible with current versions of the Microsoft Windows® Operating System. OWS-WS uses SOAP/HTTP as a transport protocol to allow for seamless exchange of information between various applications. By focusing solely on SOAP/HTTP, this platform embraces a widely accepted standard for exposing business logic, and in part shields all parties from the low-level complexities of raw XML messaging.